# Cant check if my textview that inside of an array is visible or not in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, textview, visibility

I have a 2D array (matrix) of Textviews called Board. Board has 16 Textviews in it, only one of them is invisible. In this given lines of code, I tried to find the invisible one between all the rest. For some reason, the line with the If condition collapses my app every time. I don't understand what my problem is, can someone help me?
P.S. Sorry for my English, it's not my native language.

Here is my code:

```kotlin
var i = 0
for (i in 0..4) {
    var j = 0
    for (j in 0..4) {
        var tvtemp = board[i][j]
        if (tvtemp.visibility == View.INVISIBLE) {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext,board[i][j].text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the logs that are printed when your app crashes?

Comment: OMG thank you I forgot to do it and it was so helpful! I stupidly had the loops go between 0 to 4 while my array is 0 to 3. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

== operator is used to compare the data of two variables.
Please don’t misunderstand this equality operator with the Java == operator as both are different. == operator in Kotlin only compares the data or variables, whereas in Java or other languages == is generally used to compare the references.

Solution:

```
if(!tvtemp.isVisible){
....
}
```

Comment: It's still not working. View class has no method called isVisible(), and when I try to create my own isVisible function like this: `fun View.isVisible(): Boolean {
        return this.visibility == View.VISIBLE
    }` it also doesnt work

Comment: isVisible is not a method, it is an extension variable defined in View.kt. And if you set visibility of textview to invisible then try tvtemp.isInvisible.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the isShown method. It determines if the view is visible to the user. If a view's visibility is set to be visible, but it it crossed off the screen then isShown will equal false. If you have no scrollview and all views are fitted in the activity then this could work for you

```
if (!tvtemp.isShown) {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext,board[i][j].text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
```

Comment: Also doesn't work. It looks like no matter which visibility function I use it will always crash.

Comment: can you post the logs from the crash so we can see what the error is?